# Why is this input type=time invalid in some browsers with a "stepMismatch": true?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, html-input

I have a very simple `input type=time` with a valid time value according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#time_strings):

```css
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="time" value="00:00:00.750" onchange="console.log(this.validity)" />
```

If I just run the snippet (Safari) *and edit the value (Firefox 93)*, whatever I edit it to, the input is considered **invalid** afterwards, with a  `"stepMismatch": true` validity fail reason (Safari 15, Firefox 93 and 94, MacOS 12).

What's going on here? How is `step` even working for this input type, and how to get rid of the invalid state?

Comment: `"valid": true` works fine here

Comment: Works fine for me too. I edit the value and it's all fine. Checkout your browsers versions.

Comment: Fine in chrome, I get a `"stepMismatch": true,` in safari on mac, adding `step="any"` to the input fixes it

Comment: Firefox is working fine as is (without explicit `step` assignment). Actually, it's the seconds that are throwing mismatch

Comment: According to MDN [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format) [(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step) the default step size 1 minute, so even a value having a non-zero seconds part would be considered invalid. `step="1"` will give you accuracy to the millisecond.

Comment: Just upgraded Firefox to 94 (from 93), now the error is gone. Gonna check Safari Technology Preview now.

Comment: Chrome 95 on Windows 11 I also get the error

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol So browsers that don't render this invalid are actually incorrect?

Comment: Having tested further, the `step` is actually based on the `min` if given, or the `value` otherwise. So changing the value to `00:01:00.750` comes up as completely valid, because it is exactly 1 step-size away from the default value. But `00:00:01.750` would not be, and neither would `00:00:00.250` because of the default step being one minute.

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow the seconds to be edited (presumably because of the default step size)

Comment: just choose a step size or if you want any set `step="any"`

Comment: The "standard" use-case for a `time` input is to input a time-of-day, which is typically only needed to be accurate to the minute. Even then common uses may wish to allow only hours, or half-hours, or even quarter-hours. It's relatively uncommon to need a time accurate to the second, and even less to the millisecond, but if that's what you need then `step="1"` will override the default and work as you want it to.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Please put things together in an answer. This is relevant to others for sure.

Comment: @pilchard MDN says this on `step="any"` for time inputs: *At this time, it's unclear what a value of `any` means for `step` when used with time inputs. This will be updated as soon as that information is determined.*

Comment: `any` is working on all browsers for all units for me, while `step=1` doesn't

Comment: In my current use-case I don't actually need the seconds and milliseconds, but as I'm authoring a general-use UI webcomponent that needs to cover all possible future uses as well.

Comment: @pilchard If you use  `step="any"` in Chrome, you can no longer use cursor-up/down in the input for milliseconds and seconds. Typing in a value works, as well as picking in the UI picker element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step), the default `step` attribute of an `input[type=time]` is equal to `60`, measured in seconds.

This means that in the absence of an explicit `step` attribute, the time can only be changed in multiples of one minute.

The `step` works with the `min` attribute if present, or the `value` attribute otherwise, so setting an initial `value="00:00:00.750"` means that only values that are 750ms past a given minute are considered valid, and depending on the browser and how it displays the input, this may not even be possible for the user to do.

Setting `step="1"` will give you the option to set the seconds part of the time as you wish, and `step="0.001"` should also let you set milliseconds. `step="any"` is also an option, but at this time it's not clearly defined. I personally would take it to mean it basically disables the resolution check entirely, but browsers may disagree.

Comment: `step="0.001"` kind of works, but it also results in the input displaying seconds and milliseconds even if the value doesn't ask for it. The whole UI element seems rather *"don't use"*  instable / unfinished. Having to dynamically setting step so it matches the value assigned doesn't seem like something developers should have to do. Also I don't get how using a default value for `step` makes much sense.

Comment: Also, even if you set the time to `00:00:00.000` Firefox still renders it invalid. How can that ever be invalid given whatever `step`?